# What writing styles should I follow for my SOP(Statement of Purpose) to Graduate schools in The States.

Tags: word-usage, writing, style

I'm aware of these 4 writing styles

1. Expository Writing
2. Descriptive Writing
3. Persuasive Writing
4. Narrative Writing

I have about 2 years to improve and write proficiently. Is there a particular writing style which is better appreciated?

Comment: Those are not 'styles' but purposes.

Comment: I actually read this article [link]http://hunbbel-meer.hubpages.com/hub/Four-Types-of-WritingWhat 
and got confused. What should I follow? Thanks.

Comment: There's a flaw in your link.

Comment: www.hubpages.com/hub/Four-Types-of-Writing

Comment: Ignore that: it is so general that it is entirely useless for any actual writing assignment. Study each school's description of what it wants in the SOP (or whatever it calls it); give it what it asks for; try to figure out **why** it wants that and not something else; and shape your essay to address the underlying concern. Real Writers don't worry about style (Bernard Shaw said "Effectiveness of Assertion is the Alpha and Omega of style"); they put their effort into doing the job at hand.

Comment: That boosts my confidence!

Comment: The Elements of Style by Strunk and White gives excellent advice. The clear examples and simple rules given are congruent with the style many admissions offices like to see. Listen to @StoneyB and spend time understanding the purpose of that school's writing assignment.

Comment: @Phil White is fine (Strunk has no real complicity in this work) as long as you pay no attention at all to his absurd *dicta* on "grammar".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very broad, about general writing advice, and is not a specific question about English.  Please see http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. There is a [wealth of information](https://www.google.com/search?q="statement+of+purpose"+graduate+school) online regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'style' you should follow should be that of the best conversational writing you can find in your field: not highly technical (except to the extent you address whatever research you have in mind), but the sort of language employed by established authorities in the field when they are addressing their peers, or colleagues in other disciplines, on semi-formal occasions.

But the content is far more important than the style. Pay close attention to the specific requirements of each school's prompt, and be sure you address those requirements explicitly and honestly- *"Nothing extenuate / Nor set down aught in malice."* Pay particular to attention to how the prompt implicitly defines the sort of student they are looking for. Each school has their particular strengths and purposes; they want you tell them how well your strengths and purposes suit theirs.

And if there isn't an obvious match, think very hard: do you belong in this school? Will it satisfy *your* requirements?